# update_option() passing empty array() but still updating

Tags: plugin-development, options, plugin-options

I am reviewing some code in a custom plugin but I am not understanding how it could be working.

All form fields are indexed by `name="opm_settings[name]"`

At the top of the page inside the function that draws the page is the following code:

```
    global $opm_settings;
    
    if ( array_key_exists('submit', $_POST) ) 
    {
        update_option('opm_settings', array());?> 
            
    <div id="setting-error-settings-updated" class="settings_error notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e('Settings updated.', 'opm_domain'); ?></p>
    </div>
    
    <?php }
```

In the call to `update_option()` the 2nd parameter being passed is `array()` which is just an empty array ...

THe required value is:

```
(mixed) (Required) 
Option value. Must be serializable if non-scalar. Expected to not be SQL-escaped.
```

however, the actual data in the form is getting submitted and entered into the DB, not an empty array ... How? I don't understand.

Comment: I can't say from the code that you've posted how the form data is getting entered into the DB, but there's nothing wrong with passing an empty array to `update_option()`. The fact that it's a required parameter just means that you have to have *something*. You can update an option with `null` if you choose to.

Comment: And if `opm_settings` is your database option name (registered via `register_setting()`), then why do you call `update_option()`? The settings API will automatically save the settings, so you shouldn't need to update it manually on your settings page.

Comment: @SallyCJ because I have no idea how update_options works - never used it - I am reviewing the code to try and understand so I can learn and make some modifications

Comment: Then as @PatJ said, there's nothing wrong in your call to `update_option()`, and you should include more code in your question and clarify the question - e.g. let us know what kind of answer are you really looking for.

Comment: I want to know how options are being updated when the call to update_option is updating with an empty array...